# MongoDB - Is it possible to remove all documents with a certain field referenced?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have `Documents` which have a reference key to another `Document`.
Is it possible to remove every Document which has a reference to that field in one go?

Right now, I would use `db.collection.remove(<query for the reference>)` and run it through every single collection, but this does not seem efficient at all.

What I want to do is to use one single remove query which would run through all documents. I am using the command prompt in RoboMongo.

Comment: Looks like you have bad design if you need many relations in your application just take relational database. And to regarding your question this is impossible because mongo doesn't oriented on relations at all you can do that and also make a joins but it looks like a hack for document oriented database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is **yes** you can do it.

**How you can do it:**
If you want to perform actions like that, you can write a small mongoDB script. [learn more about mongo shell scripts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

A solution to your post could be a script like that:

```
cursor = db.collection.find();
while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
   // Compare the two keys and remove the appropriate document
}
```

[MongoDB Shell Scripting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) is a good solution if you have to automate actions.

Comment: Write your script in a separate file, and call it into your MongoDB shell using: 
load("YourFile.js")